# How best to store an SQL table using Python lists and dictionaries

Tags: python

[image]

Hello I am practicing Python data structures. I want to ask the user for their ID and which year they want their information for and then be able to display all of the information to them using a list of dictionary. How is the most efficient way to do this using Python lists and dictionaries.

Example: Enter your ID
Enter the year
Iterate through list or dictionary
print info for that year

Comment: you can do this  `{<user_id> : { <year> : <data>}}`

Comment: Which data structure is this and how would i iterate through it

Comment: it is dictionary and you can access user data by just  `data[<user_id>][<year>]`

Comment: Can you write some example id's and year's so undestand it better please

Answer (score 0):

```
user_info = {
              1: {
                   2021: {'salary': 2021, 'position': 'developer'}, 
                   2022: {'salary':2022, 'position': 'senior dev'}
                 },
              2:{
                  2021: {'salary': 2021, 'position': 'BA'},
                  2022: {'salary':2022, 'position': 'senior BA'}
                }
             }
```

now in order to access user information, so for user whose user_id is 1 and for year 2021 you want to get information, you can get that by

```
information = user_info[1][2021]
print(information)
# output -> {'salary': 2021, 'position': 'developer'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How do I swap that 1 and 2 out for an employee ID that isnt an int say: P023G or ERT2

Comment: you can use them instead of 1 or 2 , [python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)